# How to pass an object to a unittest Class

Tags: python, unit-testing

Currently I use the standard form of testclasses in python unittest. For example:

```
import unittest, myTestSystem
class MyTestPackage(unittest.TestCase):

    @classmethod
    def setUpClass(cls):
        cls.sut = myTestSystem.Setup()
        cls.sut.connect(<IP>, <PORT>)

    @classmethod
    def tearDownClass(cls):
        cls.sut.disconnect()
        del cls.sut

    def test1(self):
        ret = dosomestuff()
        self.assertEqual(ret, 0)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    unittest.main()
```

However, I have several of these testsuites, because its a big package of tests. To put all in one TestClass would not be really nice. The problem is, that for each start of a testsuite I connect me to my system under test (sut), run my tests and disconnect later again.
My question is, if it is possible to have a general setup before, forward an sut object to my testclasses and run these tests, by using this sut object. (and close the connection after running all tests)

Answer (score -1):

Take a look at [py.test](http://pytest.org/latest/) it contains some nice extensions to do package level test set up.